# Unauthorized access to mongo-express using Nginx

Tags: docker, nginx, docker-compose, devops

I'm encountering an authentication issue with my mongo-express container while trying to access MongoDB. The error indicates "Command listDatabases requires authentication." My Docker Compose file appears to have the necessary configurations, and MongoDB is set up with authentication. The nginx configuration also seems correct. Could someone assist me in identifying the root cause of the authentication problem and help resolve it so that I can view my database through mongo-express on port 8081? Your guidance on troubleshooting and potential solutions would be highly appreciated.

This is my local.yml file

```
version: "3.9"
services:
  api:
    restart: always
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: ./docker/local/express/Dockerfile
    volumes:
      - /app/node_modules
      - .:/app
    depends_on:
      - mongodb
    # ports:
    #   - "2001:2001"
    environment:
      NODE_ENV: ${NODE_ENV}
      MONGO_URI: mongodb://${MONGO_ROOT_USERNAME}:${MONGO_ROOT_PASSWORD}@mongodb
      FORCE_COLOR: 1
    networks:
      - invoice

  client:
    build:
      context:  ./client
      dockerfile: ./docker/local/Dockerfile
    restart: on-failure
    volumes:
      - ./client:/app
      - /app/node_modules
    networks:
      - invoice

  mongodb:
    image: mongo
    restart: always
    ports:
      - "27017:27017"
    environment:
      MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_USERNAME: ${MONGO_ROOT_USERNAME}
      MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_PASSWORD: ${MONGO_ROOT_PASSWORD}
    volumes:
      - mongodb-data:/data/db
    networks:
      - invoice

  mongo-express:
    image: mongo-express
    depends_on:
      - mongodb
    ports:
      - "8081:8081"
    environment:
      MONGO_CONFIG_MONGODB_ADMINUSERNAME: ${MONGO_ROOT_USERNAME}
      MONGO_CONFIG_MONGODB_ADMINPASSWORD: ${MONGO_ROOT_PASSWORD}
      ME_CONFIG_MONGODB_SERVER: mongodb
      ME_CONFIG_BASICAUTH_USERNAME: admin
      ME_CONFIG_BASICAUTH_PASSWORD: admin123
    networks:
      - invoice

  mailhog:
    image: mailhog/mailhog:v1.0.0
    ports:
      - "8025:8025"
      - "1025:1025"
    networks:
      - invoice
  
  nginx: 
    build:
      context: ./docker/local/nginx
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    ports:
      - "8080:80"
    restart: always
    depends_on:
      - api
    volumes:
      - static_volume:/app/staticfiles
      - pdf_volume:/app/docs
    networks:
      - invoice

networks:
  invoice:
    driver: bridge

volumes:
  mongodb-data:
  static_volume:
  pdf_volume:
```

This is my nginx default.config file

```
upstream api {
server api:2001;
}

upstream client {
server client:3000;
}

server {
client_max_body_size 20M;
listen 80;
location /api/v1/ {
proxy_pass http://api;

        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
    
        # proxy_redirect off;
    }
    
    location /staticfiles/ {
        alias /app/staticfiles/;
    }
    
    location /ws {
        proxy_pass http://client;
    
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
    
        proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
    
        proxy_set_header Connection "Upgrade";
    }
    
    location / {
        proxy_pass http://client;
    
        proxy_redirect off;
    
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
    
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
    
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Host $server_name;
    }

}
```

Getting this error in my mongo-express container

```
No custom config.js found, loading config.default.js
Welcome to mongo-express
------------------------
/node_modules/mongodb/lib/cmap/connection.js:231
callback(new error_1.MongoServerError(document));


MongoServerError: Command listDatabases requires authentication
    at Connection.onMessage (/node_modules/mongodb/lib/cmap/connection.js:231:30)
    at MessageStream.<anonymous> (/node_modules/mongodb/lib/cmap/connection.js:61:60)
    at MessageStream.emit (node:events:517:28)
    at processIncomingData (/node_modules/mongodb/lib/cmap/message_stream.js:125:16)
    at MessageStream._write (/node_modules/mongodb/lib/cmap/message_stream.js:33:9)
    at writeOrBuffer (node:internal/streams/writable:392:12)
    at _write (node:internal/streams/writable:333:10)
    at Writable.write (node:internal/streams/writable:337:10)
    at Socket.ondata (node:internal/streams/readable:809:22)
    at Socket.emit (node:events:517:28) {
  ok: 0,
  code: 13,
  codeName: 'Unauthorized',
  [Symbol(errorLabels)]: Set(0) {}
}
Node.js v18.19.0
```

I am not able to view my database on port 8081 its empty help solving this issue
#DevOps

Comment: There is a dedicated [devops.se] site, and this question might be better asked there; it doesn't seem to be about programming _per se_.